# Mocking a Database to work with FastAPI and Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am working on a project where I am using FastAPI and pydantic. This was mentioned in the github repo from which I am taking the tasks: `We do expect you to mock a database interaction layer in any way you see fit and generate data (which can be randomized) for the purposes of this test. The implementation of this database layer is left up to you.` Github repo link: https://github.com/steeleye/recruitment-ext/wiki/API-Developer-Assessment

This is my first time working with fastapi and never heard of mocking before. I have the following code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Path
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import datetime as dt

class TradeDetails(BaseModel):
    buySellIndicator: str = Field(description="A value of BUY for buys, SELL for sells.")

    price: float = Field(description="The price of the Trade.")

    quantity: int = Field(description="The amount of units traded.")


class Trade(BaseModel):
    asset_class: Optional[str] = Field(alias="assetClass", default=None, description="The asset class of the instrument traded. E.g. Bond, Equity, FX...etc")

    counterparty: Optional[str] = Field(default=None, description="The counterparty the trade was executed with. May not always be available")

    instrument_id: str = Field(alias="instrumentId", description="The ISIN/ID of the instrument traded. E.g. TSLA, AAPL, AMZN...etc")

    instrument_name: str = Field(alias="instrumentName", description="The name of the instrument traded.")

    trade_date_time: dt.datetime = Field(alias="tradeDateTime", description="The date-time the Trade was executed")

    trade_details: TradeDetails = Field(alias="tradeDetails", description="The details of the trade, i.e. price, quantity")

    trade_id: str = Field(alias="tradeId", default=None, description="The unique ID of the trade")

    trader: str = Field(description="The name of the Trader")
     
app = FastAPI()

# data = {
#     'asset_class': 'Bond',
#     'conterparty': 'delio',
#     'instrument_id': 'AAPL',
#     'instrument_name': 'Guitar',
#     'trade_date_time':'2023-06-6 12:22',
#     'trade_details':{'buySellIndicator':'BUY', 'price':100.0, 'quantity': 10},
#     'trade_id': '11',
#     'trader':'john'
# }

trade = Trade(assetClass='asset',
    counterparty='count',
    instrumentId='AAPL',
    instrumentName='Guitar',
    tradeDateTime='2023-06-6 12:22',
    tradeDetails={'buySellIndicator':'BUY', 'price':100.0, 'quantity': 10},
    tradeId='11',
    trader='john')

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"name": "API Developer Assessment"}

@app.get("/get-trade/{tradeId}")
def get_trade(tradeId:int=Path(description="The Id of the trade you want to view")):
    return trade.tradeId

@app.get("/Trade")
def get_trade_list():
    return trade.dict()

# @app.get('/get-by-query')
# def get_trade()
```

How do I mock a database?

Comment: why not use a `dict` of `Trade` object with `id` as a key and insert bunch of object in it, ( can be random), and get from it when API gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have these simplified models:

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class TradeDetails(BaseModel):
    price: float
    quantity: int


class Trade(BaseModel):
    asset_class: Optional[str] = Field(alias="assetClass", default=None)
    trade_details: TradeDetails = Field(alias="tradeDetails")
    trade_id: str = Field(alias="tradeId", default=None)
    trader: str

...
```

Just like @Abhishek suggested in a comment, you can simply set up a super simple dictionary, with the trade IDs as the keys and corresponding `Trade` objects as the values like this for example:

```py
TRADE_1 = Trade(
    assetClass="foo",
    tradeDetails=TradeDetails(price=100.0, quantity=10),
    tradeId="1",
    trader="john",
)
TRADE_2 = Trade(
    assetClass="bar",
    tradeDetails=TradeDetails(price=200.0, quantity=1),
    tradeId="2",
    trader="alice",
)
TRADE_3 = Trade(
    assetClass="baz",
    tradeDetails=TradeDetails(price=3.14, quantity=5),
    tradeId="3",
    trader="dan",
)

MOCK_TRADE_DATABASE = {
    "1": TRADE_1,
    "2": TRADE_2,
    "3": TRADE_3,
}
```

Then you can have your endpoints set up something like this:

```py
...

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/trades/{trade_id}")
def get_trade_by_id(trade_id: str) -> Trade:
    if trade_id not in MOCK_TRADE_DATABASE:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404)
    return MOCK_TRADE_DATABASE[trade_id]


@app.get("/trades/")
def get_trade_list(search: Optional[str] = None) -> list[Trade]:
    if search is None:
        return list(MOCK_TRADE_DATABASE.values())
    # Search only for matching `trader` values:
    return [
        trade for trade in MOCK_TRADE_DATABASE.values()
        if search in trade.trader
    ]
```

If you try this out, you'll see that you can request for example specifically trade 2 via `/trades/2` and you can get an array of all trades, where the `trader` has an `a` in his/her name via `/trades/?search=a`.

If you want to get a bit more fancy, you can set up a simple [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) database instead and even allow users to add new `Trade`s to it.

But since the assignment clearly said to "mock" a database, I don't think an *actual* database (even one as minimal as SQLite) is expected.

Comment: Can I search for anything? by using the second end point?

Comment: @KarthikBhandary Do you want me to solve the entire assignment for you?

Comment: No, I figured it out! I just did not see the comment before asking

Comment: I completed the assignment as well. Thank you for the help!